# MySQL AND Query Not Working From PHP File

Tags: php, mysql

This is really bugging me now as I've got this to work in phpmyadmin but can't get it to work from my php script.

The code below is a basic php file (I'm learning) where the user submits a part number and an order number in a form which is then passed to a query (via variables), and the query result is returned to a table in the same page.

I can get it to work fine when only passing the part variable $input, but when I pass the AND criteria, no results are returned. I have checked and checked again the table and the combination tested should work. I've tried hardcoding a part number and order number combination and the same happens (okay with just the part but not when you add the AND section). Testing this part AND order combination on phpmyadmin gives the desired effects. Have I missed something?

```
<?php include 'database.php' ; ?>

<?php
$input =$_GET['part'];
$ord = $_GET['order'];
// This query works fine with just the $input criteria but when I add AND 'Order' etc... it produces zero results.
$query = "SELECT * FROM `part_status` WHERE `Part` = '$input' AND `Order` = '$ord'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$status = $result->fetch_assoc();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Part Archive</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Form for submitting the two criteria of the query -->
<form method="get" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    Part Number: <input type="text" name="part" value="<?php echo $part;?>" placeholder="Enter part number">
    Order: <input type="text" name="order" value="<?php echo $order;?>" placeholder="Enter order number">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<header><h1>Orders For: <?php echo $input;?></h1></header>

<!-- Table for displaying the result of the slq query at the top -->
<table>
    <tr><th>Part</th><th>Qty</th><th>Due Date</th><th>Order No.</th></tr>
    <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
        <tr><td><?php echo $row['Part']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row['Qty']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row['Due Date']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row['Order']; ?></td></tr>
    <?php endwhile ;?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Always grateful for any pointers or suggestions.

Comment: Did you check if `$ord` holds the value it should?

Comment: the only thing i see is $status=$result->fetch_assoc() which will get the first row (I don't know your db class, so i just guess). So if you have 1 row in return it will display nothing.

Comment: actually there is a while loop toward the bottom.

Comment: The form is using $order rather than $ord for the value of the input box

Comment: Check that input is what you expect, as well as the `$query` after `interpolation` by using: _`var_dump($_GET['part'], $_GET['order'], $query, __FILE__.__LINE__);`_ immediately after `$query = ...` statement. It should look exactly like the query that you used in `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: @dbarthel I echoed the $ord variable on running the script and it DOES return the value submitted to the form.

Comment: @RyanVincent HI Ryan, I inserted the code you gave me and it returned the same query I used in phpmyadmin. To test again, I took the result of that code snippet...     `string(9) "050209083" string(7) "5990703" string(78) "SELECT * FROM `part_status` WHERE `Part` = '050209083' AND `Order` = '5990703'" string(46) "/home/tigeecom/public_html/ismdash3/index.php7" 5990703`     and pasted it into phpmyadmin sql query and it worked. Not sure why the php code doesn't work. Is it possible I have something else wrong?

Comment: How many rows are you expecting back?  What does `$status = $result->fetch_assoc();` return? You don't appear to use it. i.e. _`var_dump($status, __FILE__.__LINE__);`_.

Comment: @RyanVincent The idea is that each line will be unique (this is the logic behind requesting the part AND order number). In the example given, the there is definitely only 1 result in the sql database and this should always be the case.

Comment: So your problem is, that you fetch the first result of your query and store it in your `$status` variable. Later on when displaying the results in your HTML markup you try to fetch the next results (which does not exist). Delete the line `$status = $result->fetch_assoc();` and your result should be presented in HTML

Comment: @dbarthel Thanks. That worked as per my answer below. I removed the while loop also as I'm guessing that wasn't necessary. I presume if there were an instance (which would be undesirable in this application) where more than one record were returned, would it simply display the first record or would the code fail?

Comment: Not used this site much before but is there a reason why my question would be down-voted? If there is something I can be doing better regarding asking questions, I'd love feedback as I am grateful for the help and want to provide the best detail upfront when asking in future.  Cheers, Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @dbarthel for this solution...
I removed `$status = $result->fetch_assoc();` and also the while loop replacing `<?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) : ?>` and `<?php endwhile ;?>` with just `<?php $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) ; ?>` and this returned a record as requested in the form.

Thanks to all for your help and support. I can now move forward and try to develop this further.